# spark cached join taking longer than uncached join

Tags: apache-spark

i have a spark job where I am repeatedly join one dataset with another data. To optimize for this I cached the frequently joined dataset. But after making the change the joins that were taking 2 secs started taking more than 5 secs.

I understand this could be happening because

1. previously some filtering was done while reading data, so i pushed all the filtering before doing caching only.
2. first time when caching is done, but i am seeing same issue in subsequent joins as well.

upon looking into logs i found

```
3/07/04 20:04:23 INFO Executor: Running task 158.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 1233)
23/07/04 20:04:23 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 31 non-empty blocks including 1 local blocks and 30 remote blocks
23/07/04 20:04:23 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 29 remote fetches in 1 ms
23/07/04 20:04:23 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_5_158 locally
23/07/04 20:04:23 INFO InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate isnotnull(id1#2) generates partition filter: ((id1.count#152 - id1.nullCount#151) > 0)
23/07/04 20:04:23 INFO InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate isnotnull(id2#0) generates partition filter: ((id2.count#147 - id2.nullCount#146) > 0)
23/07/04 20:04:28 INFO Executor: Finished task 158.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 1233). 4664 bytes result sent to driver
```

below is the log when we do join without any caching

```
23/07/04 18:01:36 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 923
23/07/04 18:01:36 INFO Executor: Running task 11.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 923)
23/07/04 18:01:36 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 35 non-empty blocks including 1 local blocks and 34 remote blocks
23/07/04 18:01:36 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 29 remote fetches in 4 ms
23/07/04 18:01:36 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 485 non-empty blocks including 17 local blocks and 468 remote blocks
23/07/04 18:01:36 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 5 remote fetches in 4 ms
23/07/04 18:01:39 INFO Executor: Finished task 11.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 923). 4226 bytes result sent to driver
```

But when join is happening without cache InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate isnotnull is missing. Hence i am suspecting it could be causing the issue. **NOTE** I have put the non null check before doing caching as well.

Is it possible to remove the InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate ?

To reproduce the issue, i wrote a sample code

```
public class TestCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Dataset<Row> userDetails = TestCode.getSparkSession().read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", "true")
                .schema(TestCode.minimumCustomerDataSchema())
                .load("info2.csv")
                .filter(new Column("account_id").isNotNull())
                .repartition(new Column("account_id"))
                .sortWithinPartitions(new Column("account_id"));

        Dataset<Row> userListOld = TestCode.getSparkSession().read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", "true")
                .schema(TestCode.minimumUserListSchema())
                .load("old.csv")
                .repartition(new Column("userid"))
                .sortWithinPartitions(new Column("userid"));
        userDetails = userDetails.cache();
        System.out.println(userDetails.count());
        Dataset<Row> oldJoin = innerJoinWithAccountToUserIdMap(userListOld, userDetails);
        persist(oldJoin);
        Thread.sleep(1000000);//so that you can visist the ui and see how the executor performed.
    }

    public static SparkSession getSparkSession() {
        return SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Customer Aggregation pipeline")
                .master("local")
                .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
                .getOrCreate();
    }

    public static void persist(Dataset<Row> dataSet) {
        dataSet.repartition(1).foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>) iterator -> {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("dumping="+iterator.next());
            }
        });
    }

    public static StructType minimumCustomerDataSchema() {
        return DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
                        DataTypes.createStructField("account_id", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true)
                }
        );
    }

    public static StructType minimumUserListSchema() {
        return DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
                        DataTypes.createStructField("userid", DataTypes.StringType, true)
                }
        );
    }

    private static Dataset<Row> innerJoinWithAccountToUserIdMap(Dataset<Row> latestRunDataset, Dataset<Row> accountToUserIdDataset) {
        return latestRunDataset.join(accountToUserIdDataset, latestRunDataset.col("userid").equalTo(accountToUserIdDataset.col("account_id")), "inner");
    }
}
```

info.csv

```
account_id,name
1,a1
2,a2
3,a3
4,a4
5,a5
6,a6
```

new.csv

```
userid
4
5
6
7
8
11
12
```

And i can see the log

```
7407 [Executor task launch worker for task 34] INFO  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryTableScanExec  - Predicate isnotnull(account_id#0) generates partition filter: ((account_id.count#40 - account_id.nullCount#39) > 0)
```

Even though i have applied same filter before doing caching, it is applied after getting read from cache. Aren't filter information retained after doing caching?

Below is the query execution plan

```
DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(userid#4.toString, account_id#0.toString, name#1.toString, StructField(userid,StringType,true), StructField(account_id,StringType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true)), obj#44: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
+- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(1)
   +- *(4) SortMergeJoin [userid#4], [account_id#0], Inner
      :- *(2) Sort [userid#4 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(userid#4, 200)
      :     +- *(1) Project [userid#4]
      :        +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(userid#4)
      :           +- *(1) FileScan csv [userid#4] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:old.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(userid)], ReadSchema: struct<userid:string>
      +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(account_id#0)
         +- InMemoryTableScan [account_id#0, name#1], [isnotnull(account_id#0)]
               +- InMemoryRelation [account_id#0, name#1], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                     +- *(2) Sort [account_id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(account_id#0, 200)
                           +- *(1) Project [account_id#0, name#1]
                              +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(account_id#0)
                                 +- *(1) FileScan csv [account_id#0,name#1] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:info2.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(account_id)], ReadSchema: struct<account_id:string,name:string>
```

if you see isnotnull filter is applied twice one during reading csv file as PushedFilters and second time in `*(3) Filter isnotnull(account_id#0)`